# how to create a list of word pairs from a list

Tags: python, list

i have a list of words in the file "temp":

```
 1. the 
 2. of
 3. to
 4. and
 5. bank
```

and so on

how do i improve its readability?

```
import itertools
f = open("temp.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
pairs = list(itertools.permutations(lines, 2))
print(pairs)
```

I am lost, please help.

Comment: What is tha expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that your problem is creating all the possible pair of words defined in the `temp` file. This is called [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) and you are already using the `itertools.permutations` function

If you need to actually write the output to a file your code should be the following:

The code:

```
import itertools
f = open("temp","r")
lines = [line.split(' ')[-1].strip() for line in f] #1
pairs = list(itertools.permutations(lines, 2)) #2
r = open('result', 'w') #3
r.write("\n".join([" ".join(p) for p in pairs])) #4
r.close() #5
```

1. The `[line.split(' ')[-1].strip() for line in f]` will read the whole file and for each readed line, it will split it around the space character, choose the last item of the line (negative indexes like `-1` walks backwards in the list), remove any trailing whitespace (like `\n`) and put all the lines in one list
2. pairs are generated like you already did, but now they dont have the trailling `\n`
3. open the `result` file for writing
4. join the pairs separated by a space (`" "`), join each result (a line) with a `\n` and then write to the file
5. close the file (thus flushing it)

Comment: No need for the `readlines`, a file object is an iterable type.

Comment: Indeed, I started from his example and did not notice

Comment: It assumes *ordered* pairs otherwise `itertools.combinations()` could be used.

Answer (score 4):

```
import itertools

with open("temp.txt", "r") as f:
    words = [item.split(' ')[-1].strip() for item in f]

pairs = list(itertools.permutations(words, 2))
print(pairs)
```

Prints (using `pprint` for readability):

```
[('the', 'of'),
 ('the', 'to'),
 ('the', 'and'),
 ('the', 'bank'),
 ('of', 'the'),
 ('of', 'to'),
 ('of', 'and'),
 ('of', 'bank'),
 ('to', 'the'),
 ('to', 'of'),
 ('to', 'and'),
 ('to', 'bank'),
 ('and', 'the'),
 ('and', 'of'),
 ('and', 'to'),
 ('and', 'bank'),
 ('bank', 'the'),
 ('bank', 'of'),
 ('bank', 'to'),
 ('bank', 'and')]
```

Comment: why is the listindex out of range?

Answer (score 2):

### Some improvements with explanations

```
import itertools

with open('temp.txt', 'r') as fobj_in, open('out.txt', 'w') as fobj_out:
    words = (item.split()[-1] for item in fobj_in if item.strip())
    for pair in itertools.permutations(words, 2):
        fobj_out.write('{} {}\n'.format(*pair))
```

### Explanation

```
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as fobj_in, open('out.txt', 'w') as fobj_out:
```

We open both files, one for reading, one of writing with the help of `with`. This guarantees that both files will be closed as soon as we leave the indentation of the `with` block even if there is an exception somewhere in this block.

We use a list comprehension to get all the words:

```
words = [item.split()[-1] for item in fobj_in if item.strip()]
```

`item.split()[-1]` strips at any whitespace and gives us the last entry in the line. Note that it also takes off the `\n` at the end of each line. No need for a `.strip()` here. `item.split()` is often better than `item.split(' ')` because it would also work for more than one space and for tabs. We still need to make sure that the line is not empty with `if item.strip()`. If nothing is left after removing all whitespace there are no words for us and `item.split()[-1]` would give and index error. Just go to the next line and discard this one.

Now we can iterate over all pairs and write them into the output file:

```
for pair in itertools.permutations(words, 2):
    fobj_out.write('{} {}\n'.format(*pair))
```

We ask the iterator to give us the next word pair one pair at a time and write this pair to the output file. There is no need to convert it to a list. The `.format(*pair)` unpacks the two elements in `pair` and is equivalent to `.format(pair[0], pair[1])` for our pair with two elements.

### Performance note

The first intuition maybe to use a generator expression to read the words from the file too:

```
words = (item.split()[-1] for item in fobj_in if item.strip())
```

But time measurements show that the list comprehension is faster than the generator expression.
This is due to `itertools.permutations(words)` consuming the iterator `words` anyway. Creating a list in the first place avoids this doubled effort of going through all elements again.